# Remove X Character occurence from Starting of string until Different Character Not found in Java

Tags: java

I am stuck in problem and not find
Solution please help me to resolve it . Below is code

```
String number = "000097127073653";

Boolean isOtherDigitFound = false;

int i=0;

for(int x=0 ; x<nunber.toCharArray() ; x++){

    if(number.toChatArray()[x] != 0 && !isOtherDigitFound ){
      isOtherDigitFound=true;
      i=x;
    }
}

number = number.subStr(x,number.length);

System.out.print(number);
```

I got the output that i wants which is 97127073653
But there is some easy way to do this .

I want to remove all occurence of 0 from Starting of string.but not from middle or somewhere else.

Example:-
I have Number like 0000123400022 then output should be like 123400022

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know that java, C and C++ are different languages?

Comment: Yes ,but logic's are same for them

Answer (score 0):

For example, the above code to work may look like this

```
    String number = "0000123400022";

    Boolean isOtherDigitFound = false;

    int i = 0;
    

    for (int x = 0; x < number.length(); x++) {

        if (number.charAt(x) != '0' && !isOtherDigitFound) {
            isOtherDigitFound = true;
            i = x;
            break;
        }
    }

    number = number.substring(i, number.length());

    System.out.print(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `replaceAll` method in Java's `String` class.

```
number = number.replaceAll("^0+", ""));
```

by adding `^` in `replaceAll` method replaces the leading characther and by adding `$` the trailing characters are replaced. So if you want to replace the trailing 0 values of the string you can do `number.replaceAll("0+$", "");`

Now you may rewrite your code to simply three lines

```
String number = "000097127073653";
number = number.replaceAll("^0+", ""));
System.out.print(number);
```

Comment: @BilalGhanchi Do not forget to accept an answer to mark this question as sloved if that answer solved your problem, to accept press the check right under the voting section of any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it something like this. Hope it's easy enough to understand.

```
    public String removingLeadingZero(final String number) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(number)) {
            return number;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (number.charAt(i) == '0') { // Here'0' can be replaced with any charater you want
            i++;
        }
        return number.substring(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are regular numbers (not containing any chars or non-numerical values), you could just cast your string to long and back. This will automatically remove all starting zeros.

```
String frontTrimmed = Long.parseLong(stringValue, 10) + "";
```